# PWA on Android doesn't allow CKEDITOR Browse server button link?

Tags: android, ckeditor

When using my website (any platform) or opening the PWA on Windows 10 the "Browse server" button in CKEDITOR opens the image uploader, but on Android using PWA, the button opens "about:blank#blocked".
Is there a workaround for this, is this expected behavior? It's not the end of the world or something, but it would be cool if this could work too.

I know this description is really short, but I don't think any further explanation is needed. The browse server button in CKEDITOR doesn't work ONLY when using PWA on Android (one of my users reported this a few days ago).

In case you want my manifest file, here you go:

```
{
  "short_name": "HSHU",
  "name": "Hearthstone Hungary",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/favicon/hshu-192x192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/favicon/hshu-512x512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "background_color": "#4285F4",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "theme_color": "#082B45"
}
```

Button (I just renamed Browse server in the localization file to "Képfeltöltés / Megtekintés"):

```
<a style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 14px; margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; user-select: none;" href="javascript:void(0)"
title="Képfeltöltés / Megtekintés" hidefocus="true" 
class="cke_dialog_ui_button" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_111_label" 
id="cke_112_uiElement">
    <span id="cke_111_label" class="cke_dialog_ui_button">
        Képfeltöltés / Megtekintés
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: show the HTML code as well in the question

Comment: What kind of html? <textarea class="ckeditor">, this? https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/

Comment: Inside browse it should have input tag as file

Comment: <a style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 14px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; user-select: none;" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Képfeltöltés / Megtekintés" hidefocus="true" class="cke_dialog_ui_button" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_111_label" id="cke_112_uiElement"><span id="cke_111_label" class="cke_dialog_ui_button">Képfeltöltés / Megtekintés</span></a>

Comment: Are you using custom WebView or native browsers?

Comment: Native. Anyway if you want, go to hearthstonehungary.hu, wait till the "Add HSHU as home screen" appear, open the PWA, and go to a comment section like this: hearthstonehungary.hu/decks/nevezd-el-magad#ujhsz